# Assigning multiple images to one UIImageView?

Tags: uiimageview, variable-assignment

In my application, if the user's calculated BMI is < 18.50, the label will show the correct classification of 'underweight'. I'd like to know if I can do this with images.

For example, if the user's BMI is < 18.50, I don't want to have to have multiple UIImageViews that would be hidden or not. I'd like to have it so that if the users BMI is a certain number, the ONE UIImageView would display the correct image needed.

My code for the label I explained above is:

```
if ([bmiView.text floatValue] < 18.50) {
    classification.text = @"Underweight";

// Desired code to go here

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have three images for each BMI and your imageview is called bmiImageView, why wouldn't you just assign the image when the BMI is calculated programmatically.

```
    if ([bmiView.text floatValue] < 18.50) {
        classification.text = @"Underweight";
        bmiImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Underweight.png"];
    } else if ([bmiView.text floatValue] == 18.50) {
        classification.text = @"Perfect Weight";
        bmiImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"perfectweight.png"];
    } else if ([bmiView.text floatValue] > 18.50) {
        classification.text = @"Overweight";
        bmiImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"overweight.png"];
    }
```